# Storing configurations in cookies with Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, session-cookies

**Use-case:**
I am currently working on a larger software, which consist of three different components. Every component has configurations, which I want to save in cookies, if the sessions is closed. If I reopening the website, the same configurations for every component should be restored.

**Here is my question:**
Is it a good practice to save all configurations in one cookie or save the configurations for a component in an own cookie?
All configurations are objects and consists of more then >10 properties.

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the configurations are to be stored for the current browser only, I would store the complete object with JSON.encode(obj) in localStore:

Something like:

```
localStorage.setItem('objectName', JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

And to get the object:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('objectName'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have access to an external API, you can save your configs in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Cookies are more server-side oriented, while localStorage is client-side.

Comment: "*Cookies are more server-side oriented, while localStorage is client-side.*" [Client-side cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) have existed since before local storage was available.

Comment: @VLAZ i think it was my bad, with the words i used to explain that. Sure they did exist, you are right there.